# Use artifacts as Jekyll assets in Github pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, github-actions

I use Gitlab pages and Jekyll to generate a website, and a python script to generate the images and data files (JSON) used by Jekyll. As I need to update these files daily, I commit and push dozens of images to update the website, which is not really convenient.

I also use Github Actions to generate and store these files as artifacts on Github:

```
- name: Main script
  run: |
    python generate_images.py --reload  # saves in folder saved_images
    # I manually commit and push these images in jekyll/assets/img to update the site
- name: Upload images artifacts
  uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
  with:
    name: saved_images
    path: saved_images
```

I would find it better to tell Jekyll to use the artifacts, instead of the committed files, so that I can update the site by just re-launching the github action (hopefully without extra commit or branch change). Actually that's what I've seen on Gitlab on another project:

```
pages:
  stage: Web_page
  before_script:
    - python generate_images.py --reload
    - cp -r saved_images/*.png jekyll/assets/img
    - cd jekyll
    - bundle install --path vendor
  script:
  - bundle exec jekyll build -d ../public
  ...
```

So I wonder if it is possible to use artifacts as Jekyll assets and data files in Github pages?